# disable duplication check and catch the duplicate record?

Tags: apex, trigger, duplicate-management, try-catch, duplicate-matching-rule

Account duplication rule is active on my salesforce that follows fuzzy matching rule for account name.I want to bypass this rule only for a particular apex class, and i used the code -

```
 Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
 dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true; 
 Account duplicateAccount = new Account(Name='duplicate'); 
 Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(duplicateAccount, dml); 
 if (sr.isSuccess()) {   
 System.debug('Duplicate account has been inserted in Salesforce!'); 
 }
```

By using this rule i bypassed the duplicate rule and saved the record ,my question is can we catch the account i bypassed and display, is that possible?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate or superseded by https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/415593/error-message-on-account-insertion-bypassing-duplication