# Error message on account insertion bypassing duplication

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, duplicate-management, duplicate-matching-rule

Account duplication rule is active on my salesforce for name of account. When i click approved from an one object an account is created, i wrote code for this using apex class. If there is no duplication detected i want to insert the record, if there is duplication i want to bypass it and display an error message, i bypassed the rule through this code -

```
                try {

                    insert acc;

                }

                catch(DmlException e){

                

                // to bypass duplicate rule

                Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();

                dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;



                // Insert account with options

                Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(acc, dml);



                if (sr.isSuccess()) {

                    System.debug('Duplicant Account inserted successfully!');

               

                } else {

                    // Handle other errors

                    System.debug('Error inserting account: ' + sr.getErrors()[0].getMessage());

                }

                }
```

But, how can i add an error message that says 'Similar account exist, please review' inside this., does somebody know this...

My apex class code is -

```
   public class ApplicantTriggerHandler {

   public static void createPartnerUser(List<Applicant__c> newList, 
   Map<id,Applicant__c> oldMap)
{
    
    
    
    List<Account> portalAccountList=new List<Account>();
    List<Account> lstExAccount = new List<Account>();
    String strRecordTypeId = [Select id from RecordType where SobjectType=:'Account' AND Name=:'Partner'].id;
    for(Applicant__c obj:newList)
    {
        if(obj.Create_Portal_User__c=='Approve' && oldmap.get(obj.id).Create_Portal_User__c!='Approve')
        {
            if(obj.Website__c != null && obj.Website__c != '')
            {
                lstExAccount = [Select id from Account where Website =: obj.Website__c limit 1];
            }
            Account acc=new Account();
            if(lstExAccount.isEmpty())
            {
                
                acc.Name=obj.Company_Name__c;
                acc.RecordTypeId = strRecordTypeId;
                acc.Type = obj.Account_Profile__c;
                acc.Phone=obj.Phone__c;
                acc.billingstreet=obj.Company_Address_Line_1__c;                   
                acc.BillingCity=obj.Company_City__c;
                
                acc.BillingPostalCode = String.ValueOf(obj.Company_postal_code__c);
                acc.billingstate = obj.Account_State__c;
                acc.billingcountry = obj.Company_Country__c;
                acc.Account_Profile__c = obj.Account_Profile__c;
                acc.currently_sell_vulnerability_scanner__c = obj.Sell_Web_Vulnerability_Scanners__c;
                acc.Services_Offered_PRM__c = obj.Services_Offered__c;
                acc.Vertical_Markets_the_Company_Serves__c = obj.Vertical_Markets_The_company_serves__c;
                acc.Country_Coverage__c = obj.Which_Countries_Do_You_Cover_New__c;
                acc.Website = obj.Website__c;
                acc.NumberOfEmployees = Integer.ValueOf(obj.Number_of_Employees__c);
                acc.Annual_Revenue__c = obj.Annual_Revenue_USD__c;
                acc.Do_you_have_an_opportunity_to_register__c = obj.Do_you_have_an_opportunity_to_register__c;
                acc.Brand_primarily_influenced_your_decision__c = obj.Primary_Influence_to_Register__c;
                
                try {
                    insert acc;
                }
                catch(DmlException e){
                
                // to bypass duplicate rule
                Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
                dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;

                // Insert account with options
                Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(acc, dml);

                if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                    System.debug('Duplicant Account inserted successfully!');
               
                } else {
                    // Handle other errors
                    System.debug('Error inserting account: ' + sr.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
                }
                }

                // Update IsPartner after insert
                acc.IsPartner = true;
                update acc;
            
                
            }
            
            
            Contact con=new Contact();
            con.LastName=obj.Last_Name__c;
            con.FirstName=obj.First_Name__c;
            con.Email=obj.Work_Email__c;
            con.Applicant__c = obj.Id;
            con.title = obj.Title__c;
            con.is_Partner_Contact__c = true;
            con.Role__c = obj.Role__c;
            con.phone = obj.Phone__c;
            con.Mailingstreet = obj.Address__c;
            con.MailingCity = obj.City__c;
            con.Mailingcountry = obj.Country__c;
            con.Mailingstate = obj.Contact_State__c;
            con.MailingPostalCode = obj.Postal_Code__c;
            
            
            if(lstExAccount.isEmpty())
            {
                con.AccountId = acc.Id;
            }
            else{
                con.AccountId = lstExAccount[0].id;
            }
            insert con;
            system.debug('**Test'+con);
            insertUser(con.id,obj.id);
            
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

how to add code for a message when it enters catch block saying duplicate account exists then save the record

Comment: Why do you need Apex? Couldn't you change the error message for the duplicate rule?

Comment: @fred,  I can't change the duplicate rule, But i want to Bypass the rule for this apex class only...

Comment: How is your Apex class different from the duplicate rule?

Comment: @fred,   I have added my apex class code in the question, In my apex class an account is created from another object when i select approved in approval status of that object. I can't alter the duplicate rule but want to bypass it with an error message., I bypassed the rule but confused on the message displaying..can you throw some light on my code on how to achieve this...

Comment: Is this truly an error message, or a warning to the user? If it is an error that should prevent the rest of the code from executing then you should use addError in your Trigger code as per the methods in the [docs here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).